# Embedded Feed Update

Tags: rss, embed, xml, feed

I am trying to embed a feed on my site. The plugin I am using is called Hungry Feed. I have the feed properly embedded and everything seems to be working except one thing. The feed updates...

How often is the embedded feed supposed to update? It seems that the feed is stuck at the articles that were available to the feed when I put the short code in my template.

The page the feed is embedded on is http://www.ragequitbaddie.com/news
The feed url that I used is: http://www.joystiq.com/editor/jessica-conditt/rss.xml

If you know of another plugin way to embed a feed that will allow me to get real time updates for a feed much like subscribing on google reader that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I dont no about the plugin, but the default on feed-function of WordPress have a cache, there cache all content for *12 hour* and then regenerate the content.
You can change this via a small function, like in a plugin or you copy the source to the `functions.php` of the current active theme; but a plugin is better for maintenance and control your install.

```
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime', create_function( '$a', 'return 1800;' ) );
```

You can change the cache time. In this example the 1800 *seconds*.

It is also possible to deacivate the cache. I doing this on my development install.

```
function do_not_cache_feeds(&$feed) {
    $feed->enable_cache(false);
}
if ( defined('WP_DEBUG') && WP_DEBUG )
    add_action( 'wp_feed_options', 'do_not_cache_feeds' );
```

See also this [Link](http://wpengineer.com/1820/feed-cache-in-wordpress/) to more background information